# How can I count some rows before inserting?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure:

```
// QandA
+----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Id |                   body                 | type | related | author_id | date_time  |
+----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | content of question1                   | 0    | null    | 12345     | 1467468795 |
| 2  | content of first answer for question1  | 1    | 1       | 53456     | 1467469311 |
| 3  | content of question2                   | 0    | null    | 43634     | 1467469512 |
| 4  | content of second answer for question1 | 1    | 1       | 43665     | 1467470098 |
| 5  | content of first answer for question2  | 1    | 3       | 43324     | 1467471291 |
+----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
/* Columns:
   type: 0 means question, 1 means answer
   related: null means question, else it's the id of its own question
*/
```

I'm trying to implement this (something exactly like what stackoverflow does). An user can ask:

- 1 question per 90 minute
- 6 question per day
- 50 question per month

So I need to count the number of previous question for an user before letting him to ask. How can I do that?

---

I have two kind of query:

**One:**

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_time)
    SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
    FROM (select count(*) as num_month,
                 count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))) as num_day,
                 count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 minute))) as num_90min
          from QANDA  
          where author_id = :id and
               type = 0 and
               date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 50 day))
         ) a 
    WHERE num_month < 50 and num_day < 6 and num_90min < 1;
```

**Two:**

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_time)
SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
FROM dual
WHERE user_id = :id 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT count(*) AS num_month
               count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))) as num_day,
               count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 minute))) as num_90min
        FROM QandA
        WHERE author_id = :id and
              type = 0 and
              date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 50 day))
        HAVING num_90min  > 50 
            OR num_day    > 6 
            OR num_month > 1 
    )
```

Ok, which one is better? Or is there a third option which is better than them?

Comment: Please provide the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE QandA/cookie\G.

Comment: @Vérace That was a typo, there isn't `cookie` table .. I've Edited ..

Comment: And can you put the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE QandA\G?

Comment: @Vérace Well I'm not sure why do you need [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V24xZ.png) for ..

Comment: I meant the text - so it can be copied and pasted. In general, it's a bad idea to post graphics of text output. And your graphic appears to have been cropped.

Comment: Clarification needed:  Does "6 per day" mean "no more than 6 in the last 86400 seconds"?  or "no more than 6 since midnight"?

Comment: @RickJames In the last 86400 seconds. "midnight" doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Counting and subqueries are somewhat costly; let's try to avoid them.

- If the latest question is less than 90 minutes ago, disallow.  This involves `MAX()` and an index on the timestamp column.
- If 6 or more today (or today+yesterday), disallow.  This involves a summary table, see below.
- If 50 or more ...  This involves the same summary table, plus a `SUM()` of only 30 rows, not 50, in worst case.  (OK that does not help much.)

Summary table something like...

```
CREATE TABLE Summary (
    author_id ...
    day DATE NOT NULL,
    ct TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, day)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Summary (author_id, day, ct)
    VALUES (:id, CURRENT_DATE(), 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ct = ct+1;

-- How many "since midnight":
( SELECT ct FROM Summary WHERE author_id = :id
       AND day = CURRENT_DATE() ) >= 6  -- disallow
-- How many "since midnight yesterday" (overkill; see below):
( SELECT SUM(ct) FROM Summary WHERE author_id = :id
       AND day >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) >= 6  -- disallow
( SELECT SUM(ct) FROM Summary WHERE author_id = :id
       AND day >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 50 DAY ) >= 50  -- disallow
```

Sinece the second only checks for "6 in the last 2 days", it needs this to further check:

```
-- Exact count since this time yesterday:
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Qanda WHERE author_id = :id
       AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) < 6
```

The query against the summary table should be faster, hence is probably worth doing as a quicker check.

I would define the limit as "6 since midnight" in order to simplify and speed up the checks.

`Qanda` needs `INDEX(author_id, timestamp)`

Comment: What do you mean `user_id` in this index? `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, day)` ? Do you mean `author_id`?

Comment: @MartinAJ - The question is about limiting what a "user can ask".  So, I assume that `user_id` identifies a "user".  The Summary table keeps track of how many questions each `user_id` has asked for each `day` (hence the PK).  From this, my query against `Summary` can _quickly_ compute the day-related restrictions.